# Calling C DLL function from C# - parameter struct too large or complex to marshal

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling, dllimport

I have a problem calling a function from a C DLL with C#. I have tried to marshal the struct, but an exception tells me that my struct is too large or too complex to marshal... I have calculated 15256 bytes for the complete size.

The original C function looks like this:

```
int32_t CN_API SetConfig(int32_t handle, int32_t bId, ModeEnum Mode, ParamStruct params);
```

The struct that I defined in C# looks like this:

```
struct ParamStruct
{
    int param1;
    ...
    //Here are some primitve arrays and variables...
    ...
    structArray1[16]
    //    |__...some integers
    //    |__structA
    //            |__...some variables

    int param8

    structB
    //    |__...some integer arrays and a float array
    //    |__structArray2[16]
    //            |__...some variables

    enum param9
    ...
    //here are some more structs and struct arrays
    ...
}
```

I know that the "syntax" isn´t correct. It´s just that you know what I mean ;).

Now I want to call this function and pass the ParamStruct to it.

My question is, how can I do that? Does anyone of you have a good idea for solving my problem?
Is it posible to do it with an IntPtr?
Or is the best way to rewrite my structure in C# so, that it is less complex?

If you need more detailed information, please telle me.

Comment: Simplest way forward will be to find a way to avoid such a large structure

Comment: I just have the dll and cannot change anything inside. What i mean is, I have to live with such a large structure.

Comment: The I think that C++/CLI is probably the best way forward. Marshalling that structure by hand from C# pinvoke will be horrible.

Comment: I found writing a simple C++ wrapper around the dll you wish to use that only takes primitive types makes pinvoke stuff much simpler. Also, if you create an instance of the struct, you could pass an IntPtr to it through to your wrapper and then 'Marshall' it within the wrapper.

Comment: @David Watts: Thanks for your answer. I have also thought about that possibility. But i hoped there a "simple" way or a workaround doin that directly from C#. There are many more functions in the DLL that are working fine. It´s only this one function I have problems with. Therefore I don´t want to write a c++ wrapper, because I have to change many things in my code if I want to do that.

Comment: Any C or C++ programmer would pass ParamStruct* instead to avoid copying such a large structure, it is very inefficient in native code as well.  Your calculation is off heavily, the pinvoke marshaller gets only grumpy at >= 65KB.  So maybe you declared the struct wrong, the only hope you have.  The value returned by Marshal.SizeOf() in C# code must match sizeof(ParamStruct) in a little C test program.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have found that the pinvoke marshaller very often "gets grumpy" when a struct contains other structs & arrays of structs & also strings. Also if the OP has a third party DLL then he is stuck with what has been done as was my situation. As far as efficiency is concerned - how often is this going to be done - 100s of times a second then my solution is a problem - once an hour (as I do) no problem at all.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It would be definitely better using ParamStruct *. But the function wants a copy of that ;). I will try the sizeof stuff. Thanks

Comment: @Stone_of_Thor if you want to pass a pointer to your struct, you could call `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to get the pointer to the struct and pass that through instead. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @David Watts: I´ve tried that earlier, but struct can´t be marshalled. Therefore when I try Marshal.StructureToPtr the exception tells me, that this is not possible.

Comment: @Stone_of_Thor Ah thats a shame!

Comment: @HansPassant: I have checked the sizes of my struct with Marshal.SizeOf and with sizeof(ParamStruct) in C. Both have the same size! I have checked my complete struct. The declaration is correct now. But now when I try to pass it, I get an error window with "vshost32.exe" doesn´t work anymore...". Could that error come from calling the function, or is there another problem? All the other functions I´m calling from the dll working fine. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DavidWatts: Thanks for you constructive input! I`ve tried Marshal.StructureToPtr again (using an IntPtr), but now I get also the error window as I wrote above to HansPassant.

Comment: Well, pretty unclear what you changed to now suddenly not get this exception anymore.  Nevertheless, crashing the native code with a subtle mistake in the data you pass through this monster struct is par for the course.  You of course have to debug the native code to have any hint what might be the cause, we can't help you do that.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved a similar problem by redefining the native method to take a byte * parameter & manually copied the struct to a byte array.

```
public override void ToByteArray(out byte[] bEeprom)
{
  int arrOffs, arrOffs1, arrOffs2;
  int length = Size();
  int ptrOffset = 0;
  byte[] convString;
  int maxLen;

  IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);

  Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, ptrOffset, renumerationMode);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(byte);
  Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, ptrOffset, (short)vendorID);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(short);
  Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, ptrOffset, (short)productID);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(short);
  Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, ptrOffset, (short)deviceID);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(short);
  Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, ptrOffset, config);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(byte);
  Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, ptrOffset, eepromVersion);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(byte);
  Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, ptrOffset, hwVersion);
  ptrOffset += sizeof(short);
  for (arrOffs = 0; arrOffs < configFlags.Length; arrOffs++)
  {
    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, ptrOffset, configFlags[arrOffs]);
    ptrOffset += sizeof(byte);
  }
......
  Debug.Assert(ptrOffset == length);

  bEeprom = new byte[length];
  Marshal.Copy(ptr, bEeprom, 0, length);
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I have since found there are more efficient ways of copying arrays (see Marshal Copy method) but haven't had time to refactor the code.

Comment: Thanks PaulF. I had the same idea using a byte array instead of a struct. But could you tell me how I exactly define the dll import and then call the function with that array?

Comment: Import as int SetConfig(int handle, int bId, int Mode, byte[] params); & call with the marshalled array.

Comment: I checked my code after & it actually passes pointer to the struct & used the following definition _"public unsafe static extern WriteEEprom(short handle, byte *eeprom)"_ & in the wrapper code along the lines of this _" byte[] bE; E.ToByteArray(out bE); unsafe { fixed (byte *pE = bE) { NativeMethods.WriteEEprom(handle, pE); } }"_  You may need to modify your code along similar lines.

Comment: I´ve tried to pass my byte array with your method. Sometimes it works but mostly I get an AccesViolationException ("Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.") The size of my byte is correct and also the values of my parameters. Do you have any idea, why this happens?

Comment: When it works - does it always work with the same data in your struct or does it sometimes fail. If you have strings in the struct - do you ensure they are zero terminated?

Comment: There are always the same data in the struct. I do never change anything. I initialize the data of the struct once and write it into the byte array. Sometimes it works, sometimes it fails. I have one string in a struct and it is zero terminated...

Comment: Can you create & initialise the struct in C & compare to your marshalled byte array (maybe output both to CSV & import into Excel) - just to ensure the marshalling is correct.

Comment: So, I have created one byte array with the struct in C and compared it byte for byte with my byte array in C#. The size and the parameters are exactly the same.

Comment: If the 2 arrays are identical & you are passing a fixed array to the unmanaged DLL then I would make the same suggestion as Hans Passant yesterday you will need to debug the native code (if that is possible).